# body selector doesn't work on firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, selector

I have a piece of code that scrolls the page when you hover an element. A strange thing that occured is that it only works for certain browsers depending on the selector in this line:              `var div = $('body');`
Using body as in this case works for Chrome but not on FF. However, replacing `body` with `html` works on FF but not on Chrome.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var speed = 10,
        timer;
    $("#hoverscroll").hover(function () {
        $(this).css({cursor: 'none'});
        $(this).css({opacity: '0'});
        var div = $('body');
        (function startscrolling(){
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                var pos = div.scrollTop();
                div.scrollTop(pos + 1);
                startscrolling();
            }, speed);
        })();
    },

    function () {
        $("#hoverscroll").css({opacity: '1'});
        clearTimeout(timer);
        speed = 10;
    })
    .click(function(){
    });
});
```

Comment: Try `var div = $('body,html');`

Comment: adding both body and html selector worked fine for Firefox, but not on Chrome. It does respond however, unlike before, but the scroll kinda bugs and goes upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `var div = $(window);`

You can `$(window).scrollTop();` because the scrollbar on a page is a part of the window, not the body, or the HTML.

However, if an element has an `overflow`, than it is a part of an HTML element.  This gets taken differently in different browsers.  However, if you are scrolling the document window, you can use `$(window).scrollTop();` that is crossbrowser compatible.